# Pandas: print if not NaN (column)

Tags: pandas, nan

I have an excel dataset with columns. The Age column has many empty cells, and I am asked to print several columns, but only print the Age if it is available. I don't want a bunch of NaN results to print. Seems straightforward, but when I try to use isnull(), it tells me the float object does not have that attribute. When I try to set == 'NaN' or '  ', I get other errors. Nothing is working, and this isn't even the point of the homework. Can someone point me in the right direction?

here is my print statement:

```
 if  ttnc_person.Age.isnull() :
              print (index, "\t", ttnc_person['Name'], pasGender)
```

was just going to do a case for if null and a case for if not, since I am a noob, so there would be an else statement for notnull if I could get the first if to work.
This is our first introduction to pandas so assume I know nothing.

Comment: You should be able to just do `ttnc_person.loc[ttnc_person['Age'].notnull(), 'Name']` I don't know what `pasGender` is but adding this to the print statement should be trvivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ttnc_person.Age` seems to be a float value, if I read your error text correctly. In this case, you can use `math.isnan(ttnc_person.Age)` to check for Nan values after importing the package with `import math`. See: [math.isnan](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan)

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `DataFrame.notna()`

```
ttnc_person[ ttnc_person['Age'].notna() ]
```

gives all columns where Age is not NaN.

```
ttnc_person.Age.notna()
```

gives only the values of the Age column.

Answer (score 0):

ttnc_person.dropna(subset=['Age'])